# Configure Mysql client timeout?

Tags: mysql, timeout

Is there a way to configure the timeout for inactive clients with mysql?

Example:
A MySQL DB has a limit of 100 client connections but some clients are not using the connection any more. I assume MySQL will eventually drop the connection but is this configurable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of `...timeout...` parameters that can be configured for a MySQL instance. Here are a few selected parameters (Ver. 8.x) for your convenience:

<sup>***Reference:*** [5.1.7 Server System Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html) (MySQL | Documentation)</sup>

#### [interactive_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout)

> The number of seconds the server waits for activity on an interactive connection before closing it. An interactive client is defined as a client that uses the `CLIENT_INTERACTIVE` option to [`mysql_real_connect()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html). See also [`wait_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout).

#### [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)

> The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a noninteractive connection before closing it.
>
> On thread startup, the session wait_timeout value is initialized from the global `wait_timeout` value or from the global `interactive_timeout` value, depending on the type of client (as defined by the `CLIENT_INTERACTIVE` connect option to [`mysql_real_connect()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html)). See also [`interactive_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout).

### Answering Your Question

> Is there a way to configure the timeout for inactive clients with mysql?

It depends. Globally you can define a timeout with the `wait_timeout` parameter of your MySQL instance. If you are using the specific option `CLIENT_INTERACTIVE` of the [`mysql_real_connect()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-real-connect.html) function, then you can use the `interactive_timeout` parameter.

Comment: Once you have decreased the timeout, I suggest you also decrease `max_connections` and `max_user_connections`.